# Count amount of words with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a page where you can read some text and click the word you got to when you finished reading. The code should then able to count the amount of words read.

I made an example

[image]

*- say I have reached the word 'some' and want to count the amount of words*

So far I figured the best way would be to make span tags around each element, and then figure it out from there. But I am kind of stuck now. Any idea?

```
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("p").append($("<span class='newclass'>").text(v));
});
```

[Here is the fiddle, don't mind the styling](https://jsfiddle.net/yd99ev9y/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd99ev9y/1/

Comment: @ChrisG Post it as an answer :D

Comment: @Nandan too late :D

Comment: Aside from the answers below, note that you can improve the logic which creates the `span` elements from the words: https://jsfiddle.net/yd99ev9y/4/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, learn something new every day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [`index()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuy--D-pnUAhXKto8KHZd_DigQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Findex%2F&usg=AFQjCNENMYfGKQCoUjBO94uh61WjLwcvyQ&sig2=9Y4Y3yAvV1n08YKlIWPNHA) function .Add the click event with [`on()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1h_Ge-pnUAhVIRo8KHZHsAPgQFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fon%2F&usg=AFQjCNFJf1Y9q7iSptlkW-9S_Ki4f0hD8w&sig2=zypELQp0WPDWqVUdeSsZgA) for dynamically append element .Then get the index  .`+1`=> index start from zero so add `+1` for the position

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
  $("p").append($("<span class='newclass'>").text(v));
});

$('p .newclass').on('click',function(){
console.log($(this).index()+1)
})
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a test bla bla bla some more words</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index()` to get the total words till the current element. Below is the code:

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
  $("p").append($("<span class='newclass'>").text(v));
});

$(document).on('click', '.newclass', function() {
  console.log("Total words: " + ($(this).index() + 1))
});
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a test bla bla bla some more words</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for a different approach of adding an `onclick` handler when you create the element as you already have the index then.

```js
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
  $("p").append($('<span class="newclass" onclick="howMany(' + i + ')">').text(v));
});

function howMany(i) {
  console.log(i + 1);
}
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a test bla bla bla some more words</p>
```